# How to handle multiple-button multiple-clicks in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have multiple buttons in a screen and all are independent like one button is for navigating to next page, another one is for a popup calendar, etc. When I click quickly on all these buttons, all clicks are triggered and I tried using disabling the buttons by using a boolean state variable. But still I can click on the button within the time I set the state. So is there any way to prevent this to happen?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Would be better to share your code

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this behavior by using setState method. However be careful, as set state is asynchronous. For simple scenario you can to do it like this:

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props); 

    this.state = {    
        enableButton: false 
    };
}
```

And then use your button or TouchableOpacity like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
        disabled={this.state.enableButton}
        onPress={() => handleMe()}>
        <Text>
            {text}
        </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

And then for enabling your button:

```
handleMe() {
    this.setState({
        enableButton: true
    });
}
```

Let me know, if you are still confused.

Comment: Cannot do like this. I  have child components with another buttons. I did it by overriding the touchableopacity of react native with my custom created one. If you want i will post here

Answer (score 0):

There might be a issue with function binding. The function might not have been binded which makes them being called even without tap.

Comment: I dont think so. Anyway thanks for your reply and i resolved it by overriding react-native's touchable opacity with a custom one.